# how to delete a saved request in chrome's arc (Advanced REST Client) extension?

Tags: httprequest, rest-client, advanced-rest-client

How to delete a saved request in chrome's ARC (Advanced REST Client) extension?

I currently have ARC extension installed in chrome and some requests saved.

I looked for, but didin't find any way to delete a request from the "saved" list.

- tried to select the request and press delete key (from keyboard), but doesn't work
- tried to find some "delete" option on the menus, but didn't find

extension link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found 2 ways:

1. There is a shortcut "CTRL + O"
2. Click in the text "Saved" in the left side bar

In both ways the Chrome's extension shows the saved requests in a list where we can select and delete individually each one.

Comment: I wonder why this is somehow counter intuitive. Could have, very well, an option to remove it from saved straight on the saved request... the tool is still great, though.

Answer (score 0):

Open History - Ctrl+H   --- from there look for the menu ... on the upper right corner

Comment: This way only works on ARC desktop client, to show requests no history.
The Chrome's extension doesn't show requests from history after "CTRL + H".

Anyway it was helpfull: after you said about the shortcut, I realized that the desktop client shows the keyboard shortcuts on the menu. And there is a shortcut "CTRL + O" that shows save requests in both: desktop client and chrome's extension. Inside the content of the "CTRL + O" we have the option to select and delete.