# how to delete a saved project in Advanced REST client standalone app?

Tags: configuration, project, advanced-rest-client

I'm trying to delete unused projects in ARC as they are stacking up. I couldn't find any setting related to this.

I found deleting an API call in ARC standalone app([how to delete a saved request in chrome's arc (Advanced REST Client) extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667235/how-to-delete-a-saved-request-in-chromes-arc-advanced-rest-client-extension)) but not for saved project

Answer (score 0):

I found it upon clicking kebab menu (vertical ellipsis) next to the project I want to delete and selected 'open details' and then there is 'delete project' button